# Field is not writeable: Account.ShippingAddress

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I was coding a trigger for automatically fill up shipping address when a account is created with billing address.
code down below

```
trigger BillingAdd on Account (before insert) {
   List<Account> accL = new list<Account>();
    for(Account acc : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(acc.BillingAddress != null)//check if billing address is not null 
            // Account acc1 = new Account();
            acc.ShippingAddress = acc.BillingAddress;

        accL.add(acc);
    }

    if(!accL.isEmpty())
    {
        insert accL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Omitting the curly braces for an `if` (or an `else if`, or an `else`) is not great practice. It is valid syntax, but it's also a way to introduce very subtle (i.e. hard to find and correct) bugs into your code.

Comment: Also, you should get rid of the `insert accL;` bit (and the `if()` that's wrapping it). The check for an empty list before performing DML is unnecessary (Salesforce does that for us automatically). The DML itself is also not needed here since you're in a `before` trigger and are making changes to the record instances in `trigger.new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billing and Shipping Address fields are [compound fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields.htm).

They're read-only (as indicated by your error) and mostly just a quality-of-life thing.

You'll need to explicitly copy each individual component of the address.
e.g.

```
acc.ShippingStreet = acc.BillingStreet;
acc.ShippingCity = acc.BillingCity;
// etc...
```

Comment: Yes , this worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Impana - as a service to the community, you should accept Derek's answer